What is the metal ledge at the bottom of the garage door?
At the center of the bottom of my garage door there’s this metal protrusion. Does it serve any purpose? Why is it there in the first place? It seems to artificially reduce the clearance from the door to the garage contents, but only in one narrow spot.


You should disconnect the GDO every 6 months or so to verify proper manual operation, and then test the safety mechanisms (break the beam, and stop and reverse when a 2x4 is laid flat on the floor) and make any adjustments needed.

@Ecnerwal I don’t follow how that’s relevant to this question.

On some doors it's there to assist you in compressing the door seal as you throw the latch bolt. The slot for the latch is often a bit lower than where it naturally aligns. This gives a better seal under the door.
It's also a lift handle to prevent you from having to jam your fingers under the door and grab the dirty seal.
In the case of rollup doors, it acts as a limit stop to prevent the door from opening too far and causing damage or jamming.
If you don't want it, just pull the two screws and remove it, then replace the screw. It's completely optional, though some jurisdictions may require it for safety.
